# How to apply object oriented design in this program?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

Write a program that has multiple classes starting with a product class. Also Computer, software and stereo classes that inherit the product class. Laptop and desktop classes inherit computer and also Home Theater and car stereo that inherit the Stereo class.
The program should allow you to enter a new product and saves it to the database. Each product is given a unique ID number based on the number of record in the file. On the details tab you can view each record in the file and see the details of each product and even modify the record.

what I did -

In DTO package,

```
public interface Product {
    public int productId();
    public String name();
    public int price();
    public String type();

    public void setName(String name);
    public void setPrice(int price);
}
```

then.. I made computer as abstract class which is extending Product(I), desktop and laptop are extending computer and overriding all the methods of product(I). Likewise, I did for the stereo.

Then, In DAO package

```
public interface ProductDao {

    public boolean addProduct(Product product);
    public boolean deleteProduct(int productId);
    public boolean updateProduct(int productId);
    public void retrieveAll();
}
```

and then I implemented this methods in ProductDaoImpl class. My program is running fine. 
But what about my design ? Is it correct ? 
if not, then please suggest me a better design.

Comment: Check this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm
should help you understand this.

Comment: Not sure why your retrieveAll() method would return void, but aside from that, I see no major issues with your design.  Did you have a specific questions regarding this structure and how it works?  Otherwise this question is a little too broad.

Comment: It's a simple easy straightforward, i think stackoverflow is not the right place to post some thin like this, or what is your issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

Bad thing about that is that you need to create for each concrete product too many classes: DTO, DAO interface, DAO implementation. Consider you have implemented many products and now need to make changes in DB access. You will need to make too many changes. Even with base class it doesn't look good.

It's better to use ORM today as it's standard way for such things. With other good approach you can easily switch DB provider even at runtime while your code seems to be very heavy for changes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now, I will go through ORM what it is and how it works. One thing I wanna ask u, is that appropriate to make computer & stereo class abstract  ?

Comment: If they share some computer-specific properties it is good to have it in abstract base class. Refer to SOLID principes, it must-have thing in today's architectures